Problems with creating my first RAG Chatbot based on Python, OpenAI API, Langchain and Pinecone
I am currently trying to solve a problem in a code I've just created a few weeks ago. Even since days of trying to solve the problem, I still can't figure out what I should do. To be honest, I am quite new in coding and just started to learn it some months ago. No matter what I do, I just don't get it. The terminal is showing me multiple errors:

File "C:\Users\secret\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\rest.py", line 261, in request
raise PineconeApiException(http_resp=r)
pinecone.core.client.exceptions.PineconeApiException: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Date': 'Tue, 07 May 2024 21:14:31 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '90', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-pinecone-request-latency-ms': '44', 'x-pinecone-request-id': '7683065097316603496', 'x-envoy-upstream-service-time': '32', 'server': 'envoy'})
HTTP response body: {"code":3,"message":"Cannot provide both 'ID' and 'vector' at the same time","details":[]}

File "c:\Users\secret\Documents\FAil.py", line 42, in embed_and_index_documents
index.upsert(vectors=[(str(doc.id), embedding, {"text": doc.page_content})])
^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute 'id'


Whenever I solve one problem, another one appears. So if you guys could check my entire Code and help me with it, I'd be super grateful!!
Thank you all in advance and have a nice day!
import os
import openai
from openai import OpenAI
from langchain_community.document_loaders import TextLoader
from langchain_text_splitters import CharacterTextSplitter
from pinecone import Index

# API-Keys setzen
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "secret"
os.environ["PINECONE_API_KEY"] = "secret"
os.environ["PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT"] = "us-east-1"

# OpenAI Client initialisieren
client = OpenAI(api_key=os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"])

# Pinecone Index initialisieren
index = Index(
    index_name="secret",
    host="secret",
    api_key=os.getenv("PINECONE_API_KEY"),
    environment=os.getenv("PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT")
)

# Dokumente laden und aufteilen
loader = TextLoader("C:/Users/secret/OneDrive/secret.txt")
documents = loader.load()
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=0)
docs = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

# Funktionen definieren
def embed_and_index_documents():
    """Dokumente in Embeddings umwandeln und in Pinecone indexieren."""
    doc_id = 1  # Starten mit einer ID von 1
    for doc in docs:
        # Text aus dem Attribut `page_content` verwenden
        response = client.embeddings.create(
            model="text-embedding-ada-002",
            input=[doc.page_content]  # Liste von Strings für die Batch-Verarbeitung
        )
        embedding = response.data[0].embedding
        # Vektoren und Metadaten korrekt an Pinecone senden
        index.upsert(vectors=[(str(doc_id), embedding, {"text": doc.page_content})])
        doc_id += 1  # Erhöhen der doc_id für das nächste Dokument


def ask_question(question):
    """Eine Frage beantworten, indem zuerst der Pinecone-Index abgefragt wird und dann eine Antwort generiert wird."""
    response = client.embeddings.create(
        model="text-embedding-ada-002",
        input=[question]
    )
    question_embedding = response.data[0].embedding
    results = index.query(positive_vectors=[question_embedding], top_k=3)
    document_ids = [result.id for result in results["matches"]]
    documents = [index.fetch(ids=[doc_id]).get(doc_id).metadata["text"] for doc_id in document_ids]

    # Das Foundation Model nutzen, um eine Antwort zu generieren
    context = " ".join(documents)
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        model="text-davinci-002",
        prompt=f"Answer the question based on the text: {context}\n\nQuestion: {question}",
        max_tokens=150
    )
    return response.choices[0].text

# Dokumente indexieren
embed_and_index_documents()

# Frage stellen und Antwort erhalten
response = ask_question("Why are dolphins so funny?")
print("Antwort:", response)

As already mentioned, I tried anything possible - saw through all kinds of docs, checked my code multiple times, looked through various communities & asked ChatGPT for help, so please help!
